# javax.net.ssl.SSLException ao enviar mail usando JavaMail

Tags: java, javamail

Bom dia. Estou com problemas ao enviar um e-mail utilizando o JavaMail.

Retorna a seguinte exceção:

> (javax.mail.SendFailedException)javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed; nested exception is: class javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Eu já analisei outras perguntas, como, por exemplo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157592/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-when-sending-mail-using-javamail

Entretanto o erro ainda persiste.

Obs.: Já deixei ativado a opção para permitir aplicativos menos seguros da minha conta no Gmail. Além disso, utilizando o Glassfish aplicação consegue fazer o envio do e-mail. Aparentemente o problema está no Apache Tomcat.

Segue o código:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session1 = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("email", "senha");
        }
    });

/**
 * Ativa Debug para sessão
 */
session1.setDebug(true);

try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session1);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("enviaremail")); //Remetente

    String destinatario = (String) session.getAttribute("email");

    Address[] toUser = InternetAddress //Destinatário(s)
        .parse(destinatario);

    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
    message.setSubject("Novo E-mail!"); //Assunto
    message.setText("Olá. Você recebeu um novo e-mail.");
    /**
     * Método para enviar a mensagem
     * criada
     */
    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Feito!!!");

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho esse exemplo que funcionou comigo com o GMAIL estava com o mesmo problema de SSL. Lembrando que tinha que configurar no GMAIL uma senha que gera lá também, se não fizer isso não dá certo, só não lembro aonde é.

```
private void sendEmail (Usuario usuario) throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.from", "edersonsergiocoelho@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom();
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "edersonsergiocoelho@gmail.com");  
    // also tried @gmail.com
    msg.setSubject("Recuperação De Senha - ESC Pizzaria");
    //msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText("Usuário: " + usuario.getLoginUsuario() + "\n" + 
                "Este e-mail foi enviado por: http://www.escpizzaria.com.br" + "\n" + 
                "Você recebeu esta e-mail, pois você esqueceu sua senha na ESC Pizzaria." + "\n\n" + 
                "------------------------------------------------" + "\n" + 
                "IMPORTANTE!" + "\n" + 
                "------------------------------------------------" + "\n" + 
                "Se você não solicitou este lembrete de senha, por favor IGNORE e EXCLUA este e-mail imediatamente." + "\n\n" +
                "Dados Da Sua Conta:" + "\n" + 
                "Nome Do Usuário: " + usuario.getLoginUsuario() + "\n\n" +
                "Acesse O Link Abaixo Para Trocar A Senha: \n\n" +
                "http://localhost:4200/usuario/trocarSenha/" + usuario.getLoginUsuario() + "/token/" + usuario.getTokenAlterarSenhaUsuario() + "\n "
                );

    Transport transport;
    transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect();
    msg.saveChanges(); 
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}

private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private PasswordAuthentication passwordAuthentication;
    public Authenticator() {

        String username = "teste@gmail.com";
        String password = "mnmzczvfwzsubrev";
        passwordAuthentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return passwordAuthentication;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Estava no SSL!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou.